# SQL selecting rows from two seperate tables with one being selected at random

Tags: mysql, sql

I am currently developing a multiple choice football quiz driven by a back end database. For my database I have created 2 tables.

The first table is called questions and contains the following data

Id, Team1, Team2, Score1, Score2, Year and Round as the attributes

The second table I have is for answers and contains the following data

Id and Team

Sample Data is shown below

Questions:

1,Spain,Holland,0,0,2010,Final
2,England,Germany,1,4,2010,Last 16

Answers

1,England
1,France
1,Germany
1,Brazil
1,Spain
1,Holland

I have kept the Id of all teams as 1 so that they can all be in the same answer set when called

The purpose of my application is to ask a question to the user using a template as shown below

```
$thisQuestion = 'Which team defeated '. $team1.' '.$score1.' - '.$score2.' in the '. $round .' of the '.$year.' world cup';
```

Below the question I wish to have 4 teams shown to the user as possible answers with 3 being drawn randomly from the answers table and the 4th being the correct answer.

So far I have only been able to call 3 random teams from the answer table using the following code

```
$sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM answers2 WHERE id=1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3");
```

Any help would be appreciated

The full sample code for the page is shown below

```
    <?php 

session_start();
require_once("scripts/connect_db.php");
$countArray = "";
if(isset($_GET['question'])){
    $question = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', "", $_GET['question']);
    $outputText = "";
    $answerText = "";
    $r = "";
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM questions");
    $numberOfQuestions = mysql_num_rows($sql);
    if(!isset($_SESSION['a_array']) || $_SESSION['a_array'] < 1){
        $currQuestion = "1";
    }else{
        $countArray = count($_SESSION['a_array']);
    }
    if($countArray > $numberOfQuestions){
        unset($_SESSION['a_array']);
        header("location: menu.php");
        exit();
    }
    if($countArray >= $numberOfQuestions){
        echo '<p>There are no more questions. Please enter your name and click next to find out your score</p>
                <form action="userResults.php" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="complete" value="true">
                <input type="text" name="username">
                <input type="submit" value="Finish">
                </form>';
            $outputText = ''.$r.','.$answerText.', ';
            echo $outputText;

        exit();
    }

    $singleSQL = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE id='$question' LIMIT 1");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($singleSQL)){
            $id = $row['ID'];
            $team1 = $row['Team1'];
            $team2 = $row['Team2'];
            $score1 = $row['Score1'];
            $score2 = $row['Score2'];
            $round = $row['Round'];
            $year= $row['Year'];
            $thisQuestion = 'Which team defeated '. $team1.' '.$score1.' - '.$score2.' in the '. $round .' of the '.$year.' world cup';

            $question_id = $row['ID'];
            $r = '<h2>'.$thisQuestion.'</h2>';
            $sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM answers2 WHERE id=1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3");
            while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)){
                $answer = $row2['team'];
                $correctAnswer = $team2;
                $answerText .= '<label style="cursor:pointer;"><input type="radio" name="rads" value="'.$correctAnswer.'">'.$answer.'</label> 
                <input type="hidden" id="qid" value="'.$id.'" name="qid"><br /><br />
                ';

            }
            $outputText = ''.$r.','.$answerText.',<span id="btnSpan"><button onclick="post_answer()">Submit</button></span><br />';
            echo $outputText;
           }
        }


?>
```

Comment: There are plenty of people who can help, but please provide a little more info. Like some sample data from the tables and an example of the output you're looking for. Plus an explanation of what is meant by "team" and how that plays into the result.

Comment: Maybe use a union, have the correct answer returned on it's own, and three randomly selected incorrect answers unioned to the bottom.

Comment: I don't want the correct answer to be called in the same place every time. is there a way around this

Comment: anyone else able to help?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer but I think you can easily expand it to do what you want. The main problem (as I understand it) is this: you need a list of four team names randomly selected except it must include one specific team name and with all 4 arranged randomly.

It turns out to be fairly simple in MySQL. Here is a simple table containing just the team names for illustration.

```
CREATE TABLE Teams (
  Team VARCHAR( 20 )
);

insert into Teams( Team )
  SELECT 'Spain' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Holland' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'England' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Germany' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Brazil' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mexico' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Uraguay' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Sweden' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'France';
```

Then get Team1 from your question. Here I've just set it to a value.

```
set @Team1 := 'Germany';

select Team
from(
  SELECT Team
  FROM Teams
  WHERE  Team <> @Team1
  ORDER BY Rand()
  limit 3
) T
union all
SELECT @Team1
order by Rand();
```

This produces four different names each time you execute it, except that the list will always include Germany. You might consider changing the last line to `order by Team` as a random list of names will still be random if arranged in alphabetical order.